# How to change the update server for Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I want to have Firefox automatically update from my own server. "app.update.url" looks like the right place in about:config, but it does not do anything.

Comment: Not really programming related.

Answer (score 6):

You need to edit the default value for "app.update.url" in defaults/prefs/firefox.js in the firefox install directory. Firefox purposely ignores user set values to "app.update.url". Then you are free to serve up whatever update.xml you want from the server you set.

Comment: Almost a shame you can't vote yourself up...